# Ammeter ideal for testing, leaving on work bench for long periods

Tags: current-measurement, meter

I am currently working on my first li-poly power supply, and I am testing Texas instruments BQ21040 PMIC.

The device has three charging phases that I need to monitor to do some troubleshooting.

I was using my Fluke branded digital multimeter to monitor charge current between the battery and output pin of the PMIC, but it wasn’t practical because the multimeter Kept powering down after a few minutes of runtime, and that halts the PMIC cycle, I believe.

I’m looking for an ammeter that is ideal to leave in a circuit for relatively long periods of time, something that could be left on your desk and you wouldn’t have to “baby-sit” it.

Rookie in the Electrical Engineering field so not sure of a the classification or specs to the ammeter I’m looking for. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: There are no Fluke DMM's that disconnect the load when used as an ammeter and powered off. You can disable the power down (if you post the model I can probably look it up for you). If you really want it to stay up, connect the IR data sender adapter and log the data to a computer.

Comment: @DrFriedParts  It’s a Fluke 117. And is that adapter an add-on accessory? I don’t remember my model shipping with anything but the two test leads.

Comment: I was mistaken, actually I don't think that model can connect to a PC... but, yes, for other models, it is an adapter sold separately.

Comment: Are you talking about the Fluke pc3000 FC Wireless PC adapter? Can Fluke-117 use that?

Comment: @DrFriedParts man I feel pretty ripped off right now. The Fluke-117 isn’t even the cheapest model in the line up, yet it can’t connect to pc. Wish I would of made that consideration before I bought it.

Comment: I use a nodeMCU ($4) and an INA219 module ($2); simple, cheap, data-logging or live, and easily precise enough for most purposes.

Comment: @iam don't feel ripped off. You have a solid entry level multimeter. A logging-capable one might be 4 times the price, nice to have but you could spend that on a lot of other test gear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation you *may* find it worthwhile to get a “bench” DMM. It will be line-powered instead of battery powered, so does not need to auto shutoff, and some models have other features which may be useful to your work such as built-in logging and graphing.

Comment: Yeah your right, unfortunately. Keeping a battery powered multimeter from sleeping doesn’t sound that wise, not sure how long battery charge last.

Answer (score 3):

### Disable Auto Power Off (Fluke 115 & 117)

All the ways...

1. The Meter automatically enters "Sleep mode" and blanks the display if there is no function change, range change, or button press for 20 minutes.
2. Pressing any button or turning the rotary switch awakens the Meter.
3. **To disable the Sleep mode, hold down the yellow button while turning the Meter on.**
4. The Sleep mode is always disabled in the MIN MAX AVG mode.